# Setup Botpress on VPS

Tags: bots

So I am able to setup Botpress bot engine to my Alibaba Cloud VPS instance but immediately I exit the terminal, the engine stops. Would anyone kindly help me know how to persist the instance after I exit the terminal. I am using the pre-compiled binaries. I ran this on the terminal:

```
./bp
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figure it out, it is as simple as adding the & at the end of the command like so:

```
./bp &
```

Will share other methods